# Makefile still returns error

Tags: makefile

I still get error when i try run this

```
OS=$(shell uname -s)

#################################################################
printVar:
        ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
        @echo $(OS)
        endif

all: 
        make -j3 -f $(MAKEFILE)
```

**terminal**

```
$ make printVar
ifeq (Darwin,Darwin)
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `Darwin,Darwin'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq (Darwin,Darwin)'
make: *** [printVar] Error 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want a tab before `ifeq`/`endif` as they are not *commands*:

```
OS=$(shell uname -s)

#################################################################
printVar:
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
    @echo $(OS)
endif

all: 
    make -j3 -f $(MAKEFILE)
```