# shell uname -s falling into linux instead of darwin

Tags: shell, makefile, uname

I was looking at [makefile returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049862/makefile-still-returns-error)
and tried

```
OS := $(shell uname -s)
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
   #set LIB_DIR
   LIB_DIR=darwin64_gcc42/lib
else
   LIB_DIR=linux64_gcc44/lib
endif
```

but for some reason, it's setting the dir as linux.  Any idea why, or how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Add in: `$(info OS = '$(OS)')` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The shell script winds up in a build output directory, and I was editing the original version, running the one in the build output dir.  *thump forehead now*